# Big O and program calls with varied input sizes

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

Suppose I have a program p that has time complexity $O(n)$ and a second program q that calls program p $m$ times. If we know the input size of p will be the same every one of those times (n), we can say that the complexity of q is $O(m \times n)$. This case sounds pretty simple to me.

However, suppose the input size of p varies over these $m$ times, from $0$ to $m-1$.

If we knew that p ran precisely $f(n) = a \times n$ instructions for an input of size $n$, it would be simple: q would run $a \times 0 + a \times 1 + \ldots + a \times (m-1) = am(m-1)/2$ instructions exactly, which is $O(m^2)$.

However, in this case, all we know is that $f(n)$ is below $a \times n$ for all $n$ greater than some $n_0$, by the definition of big-O. We can't say for sure that $f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(m-1)$ is below $a \times 0 + a \times 1 + \ldots + a \times (m-1)$, because we don't know that $0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ are greater than this $n_0$. For this reason, I don't think we can say that q runs in $O(m^2)$.

Is there a way, in this case, when all we know is the big-O behaviour of p, to analyze q?

What if we replace all the big-O's with big-Theta's?

Comment: You can in fact say that such a constant exists for all $n < n_0$: just take $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n_0} \{f(i)\}$; whenever you know that for almost all $n$ some bound holds, then you can just take the maximum/minimum over all the finitely many $n$ where it doesn't hold and scale it appropriately for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since you did not specify what q does beyond calling p, there is too little information to know anything about the time complexity of q, except that it is $\Omega(m)$ since it must execute at least $m$ calls to p, whatever else it does.

Let's look at a special case which is probably what you were thinking of. Suppose that q looks like this:

```
data := preprocess(input);
for i = 0 to m -1 do
    data := p(data);
end
```

That is, p potentially has access to all the internal data of q. This is the most general case. Where this program is not general is that **in the loop, it does nothing but call p**.

The running time of this program is $Q = A + \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} P(S_i) \right) + O(m)$ where

- $A$ is the time taken to run the preprocessing step;
- $P(s)$ is the maximum time taken by p to process data of size $s$;
- $S_i$ is the size of `data` when the $i$th step starts.

The assumption on the running time of p is that $P(s) = O(s)$. That is, there exists $n_0$ and $a$ such that if $s \ge n_0$ then $P(s) \le a \, s$. This gives us a bound for the running time when $s$ is large. When $s$ is small, we can simply use the maximum running time of p for small sizes: there are only a finite number of sizes that are smaller than $n_0$. Let $\hat P = \max\{P(0), P(1), \ldots, P(n_0-1)\}$.

Then, expanding the definition of $O(m)$ in the equation for $Q$ above, we get that there exist $m_0$ and $b$ such that for $m \ge m_0$,
$$ \begin{align}
  Q &\le A + \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} P(S_i) \right) + b m
     \le A + \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \max \{\hat P, a\, S_i\} \right) + b m \\
    &\le A + \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} (\hat P + a\, S_i) \right) + b m
     \le A + a \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} S_i \right) + (b + \hat P) m \\
    &\le A + a \left( \max\nolimits_{i=0}^{m-1} S_i \right) m + (b + \hat P) m
\end{align} $$

Notice how the constant $\hat P$ resulting from the small cases of running the subprogram has been absorbed into the multiplicative constant for the calling program. This is a general phenomenon: when studying the complexity of algorithms, the performance of subtasks on small inputs is irrelevant for obtaining a first bound on the complexity of the whole task. It can be relevant to prove better bounds (sometimes, the inequalities above are too crude).

We aren't quite there yet: the component $\max\nolimits_{i=0}^{m-1} S_i$ remains unevaluated. The behavior of this component depends on what p does. For example, if p is a program that duplicates its input, say

```
return arg ++ arg
```

where `++` is the string concatenation operator and string concatenation takes $\Theta(n)$ where $n$ is the length of the string, then $S_i = S_0 2^i$ and all the analysis above tells us is that $Q$ grows exponentially with $m$ — which is the case.

If we additionally assume that **p does not change the size of the data** and that **the preprocessing step is linear in the size of the input**, then $S_i$ does not depend on $i$ and is $O(n)$ (i.e. $S_i \le S n$ for large enough $n$), and we have (for sufficiently large $n$ and $m$):
$$
  Q \le a' n + S n m + (b + \hat P) m
$$
For sufficiently large $n$ and $m$, the dominant term is $S n m$: the time complexity of Q is $O(m n)$.

Note again that the reason why it took a lot of additional assumptions to prove that Q runs in $O(m n)$ is not the running time of p on smaller inputs, it's because for all we knew p could receive some very large inputs.

Comment: "If we know the input size of p will be the same every one of those times (n)" - does this not cover everything we need to know about the input of p?

Comment: @G.Bach The question is about “However, suppose the input size of p varies over these m times”. And “0 to m-1” is underspecified, since it doesn't give the scale.

Comment: Ah, of course I had forgotten that part and failed to read it again. I don't understand how the bound of $m$ is underspecified.

Comment: @G.Bach Ah, that one is my mistake, I overcomplicated this a little.